Did Ulam discover category theory?
(The following query by Noam Zeilberger has recently appeared on the Categories mailing list; I am taking the liberty of asking it here.)
In Ulam's autobiography Adventures of a Mathematician, there appears the following passage where he talks about his Master's thesis at the Lwów Polytechnic Institute:

I worked for a week on the thesis, then wrote it up in one night, from about ten in the evening until four in the morning, on my father's long sheets of legal paper. I still have the original manuscript. (It is unpublished to this day.) The paper contains general ideas on the operations of products of sets, and some of it outlines what is now called Category Theory.

After quoting this passage, Noam writes, "According to the information I found online, the Stanislaw M. Ulam Papers are stored in the American Philosophical Society library in Philadelphia, and include copies of both his Master's thesis in Polish titled "O operacje produkto" as well as a 1973 English translation "On the operation of product". But I was not able to find digital copies of these."
One respondent said (in essence) that it would not be surprising if Ulam had used specific examples of functors and natural transformations but without developing any general theory of them. Another suggested that "category theory" could very well refer to a theory about first or second category in the sense of Baire, not the Eilenberg-Mac Lane notion. It also occurs to me as I write this that in topology there is also the concept of Lyusternik–Schnirelmann category.
Does anyone have any idea what Ulam meant?

I have never used it but there seems to be a way to request an electronic copy: https://search.amphilsoc.org/collections/view?docId=ead/Mss.Ms.Coll.54-ead.xml

How is the recovery of "O operacje produkto" going? Are there any updates?

@M.Lonardi Not going well on my end; every time I've tried, the login has failed. But I think Noam Zeilberger might have gotten through. I'm sure that if he has success, he'll report back at the Categories mailing list, if not here, in which case either he or I will give an update.

I think I successfully made the request through their system and that it is being processed.  I did not get any email confirmation and the status of the request was just listed as "Incoming Offsite Photoduplication" every time I logged in, but logging in now I see that it changed to "Reference Digitization In Progress" on the 17th, so that sounds very promising.

Not discovered, but Ulam might have anticipated some aspects of category theory and possibly influenced Eilenberg. Kuratowski's comment on Ulam's 1932 Master's thesis  reads:"The work is a study or the 'product' operation... in relation to problems in set theory, group theory, topology, metric space geometry, combinatorics and measure theory in connection with probability" (quoted from Krzysko's obituary). Ulam himself writes about "treating very abstractly the idea of a general theory of many variables" there.
Product
measures were introduced by Lomnicki and Ulam in Sur la théorie de la mesure dans les espaces combinatoires et son application au calcul des probabilités (1934). Some of what Ulam was up to can be gleaned from von Neumann's 1936 letter to him (quoted from Mauldin):

"I agree wholeheartedly with your plans to write an up-to-date presentation of measure-theory. Caratheodory's exposition, which is perhaps the relatively best
one existing, is hopelessly obsolete. A thoroughly modern one as much combinatorial and as little topological as possible, making extensive use of finite and infinite direct products, and — above all — interpreting measure much more as probability and much less as volume, would really be a very good thing. At least I often felt how badly such a thing is lacking in the present literature... I [am] looking forward, too, with great interest for your mscr. on the general product operation."

This does not sound related to Baire's category, and the latter topic would not be called "category theory" in 1976, when Ulam wrote, either. Ulam's claim is generally taken as Polish school exploring some ideas of category theory in the 1930s. Eilenberg was Polish and got his PhD from the University of Warsaw in 1936. One of his thesis advisors was Kuratowski, same as Ulam's.
Of course, some ideas do not amount to discovering category theory, which is more than abstract treatment of products. MacLane in The development and prospects for category theory is even more categorical (pardon the pun):

"Stan Ulam, who in his autobiography, claimed to have invented, but not published, ideas on categories in Poland in the early 30's. I sharply doubt this claim; I knew Ulam well in the late 1930's, and could not then discern any interest on his part in such conceptual developments."


does not sound related to Baire's category --- The excerpt from Ulam's autobiography is clearly (to me, at least) not about Baire category. Also, "Oxtoby" in the index (chosen because of the Oxtoby-Ulam theorem in ergodic theory, which is a Baire category "almost all" result), leads to this on pp. 84−85: Right off, we started to discuss problems concerning the idea of "category" of sets. "Category" is a notion in a way parallel to but less quantitative than the measure of sets—that is, length, area, volume, and their generalizations.

r.e. the OP's excerpt: I initially considered but then dismissed that it could have referred to notions involving "operations of sets" as mentioned in this MSE answer (and Kantorovitch/Livenson papers I & II, and subsequent work by several Russian mathematicians).

Thanks, Conifold. The title of my post was a little bit clickbait-y, because I strongly incline to Mac Lane's side: this was almost certainly a piece of bravado on Ulam's part (as well as some regrettable "flag-planting"). It's one thing to discover a universal property or two; it's another to pin down what a natural transformation is, by having to conceptually backtrack from there to functor, and from functor to category, and to realize that "category" could mean far more than "collection of structured sets, and functions preserving that structure". The Ulam advocates are pushing it.

First of all, we should define what we mean by category theory.
In the narrow sense, IMHO, it says that in your profs, you are allowed to use function composition, and all your proofs will be manipulations of paths in directed graphs.

Thanks @Conifold for the pointers, and thanks Todd for posting here. For the record, my original Q re: Ulam was "Without wanting to read too much into his offhand remark, I'm curious about what he was talking about". It is interesting to see Mac Lane's negative reaction, and understandable given Ulam seemed to suggest having written up the "outlines of category theory" in a night. OTOH, Ulam's master's thesis is an actual document, which is why I wondered what he really meant by the cryptic remark, beyond bravado. From the Kuratowski quote, it sounds like it did have some conceptual content.

@Conifold in relation to "Ulam's claim is generally taken as Polish school exploring some ideas of category theory in the 1930s", do you have any other source for that? I looked at the history of the Wikipedia article itself, and it seems the original claim of the claim was added over twenty years ago by one editor without giving any sources. I asked about it on the article talk page, and the editor responded that he thinks it was 'some edition of the "Scottish Book"' but he's not sure. I couldn't find anything like that searching through the Birkhäuser 2nd edition.

I noticed that the Mauldin article you linked to includes this quote: "He could not hold still for the time it would take to learn, let’s say. modern abstract algebraic geometry, nor could he put up with the generalities of category theory."  So that sounds like a relevant bit of context for interpreting Ulam's remark.

(of course, I landed on this page by searching for links between Ulam and category theory :-)

@NoamZeilberger MacLane's remark seems to me an indication of how it was generally taken, and the context pretty much rules out Baire category interpretation. I've seen Wikipedia's claim repeated, in this 2004 thesis, for example.

@Noam Zeilberger: The Mauldin quote probably needs a bit more context, since it's my understanding (from Ulam's autobiography, which I've read twice but this was back in 1977 and sometime in the mid 1980s) and the 2020 movie about him (which I saw about a year ago) that Ulam's ability to concentrate for long periods of time was severely compromised after his early 1946 near-death encephalitis attack.

@NoamZeilberger Thanks for joining the discussion. You're right to withhold judgment until you can see the actual document (I tried to use AEON myself, but my login attempts kept failing). I understand from the mailing list that you've requested an English translation, and I'm looking forward to hearing more if and when you get it.

@Conifold re: that 2004 master's thesis, "repeated" is the right word, if you look at the text it seems to have been simply lifted from the Wikipedia article without attribution! Going back to the Mac Lane article, he mentions that Ulam's name came up during a ECCT meeting where the question arose of how category theory might have appeared if Eilenberg and Mac Lane had not formulated it. I gather that's referring to the "ECCT Tours 1994 Conference", since the article is contained in those proceedings. Perhaps there is someone who was at that meeting who remembers how that conversation went?
